# How to save checkboxes that have been checked?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim chcboxes() As CheckBox = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3}
For i As Integer = 0 To chcboxes.Length

    If (chcboxes(i).CheckState = CheckState.Checked) Then
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into array_tbl(array_id,answer) values ('" & i & "'  , '" & CheckBox1.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in array.exe
>
> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: You really ought to have been able to work this out for yourself. There's only one index being used in that code and particularly on the line that threw the exception. What was the value of that index when the exception was thrown? Does that value make sense? What is the valid range in that context?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing at all to do with SQL Server, so I have removed that tag.

Comment: Sorry but im just a beginner on this portion. Can you put in laymans term while explaining. I dont understand some

Comment: Can you help me to debug my code ? Thanks in advance

Comment: In layman's terms, open a search engine and type "vb.net indexoutofrangeexception" and then do some reading. Learn what that exception means and what conditions cause it.  You should be able to let a fair bit from the name. It tells you that an index is out of range. How many indexes are there on the line that threw the exception?  What are the values of those indexes? What are the valid ranges? Being a beginner does not preclude you from using basic logic and reasoning. As for debugging, use the same search engine to search for "vb.net debugging". Post here last. Do what you can first.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000, assuming WinForms, it would the `Checked` property that is of interest, unless `ThreeState` is set to `True`.

Comment: For the record, I'm not saying that we can't or won't help you further but you have a responsibility to do what you can for yourself first before asking for help here. No one knows how to debug before they know and information on the subject is sorely lacking in many classes and tutorials but, fortunately, we have unprecedented access to information these days so finding information for yourself on the subject is easy. Do what research you can and do what you can to implement it. When you've done all you can for yourself, that is the time to post a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Change `For` condition to:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To chcboxes.Length - 1
```